# ie8 (internet explorer 8) standalone for windows 7 64bit

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a need of using two applications,  one too old that runs only on ie8 and lower versions and one that runs on ie9 and newer versions.
All compatibility modes and quirks mode do not work well for me.

Like I said I need them both to run on the same windows7 computer while ie9 is tied to my windows and the ie8 is a standalone browser.

Tried using IECollection but they don't Support ie8 on windows7...

Did anyone encounter this problem before or have a solution for me?

Thank you for your help,
Idan BM

Comment: Never had much luck with "portable ie" downloads out there. You could use the virtual machines's on [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/en-us).

Comment: Alternatively, you could try IE11's Enterprise Mode, which is a more faithful reproduction of IE8's functionality than IE8 standards mode.  (Note that it requires Windows 8.1) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx#enterprise_mode for details.

Comment: Assume I will have windows 7 only. And I need specifically ie8 standalone and ie9 tied to windows. No other ie versions.  Thank you